# type error message - function not recognised as a function when passed as a prop to click event (newbie here)

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and I'm trying to code along to this tutorial to make a multi page login form: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zT62eVxShsY&t=1280s (26.18 mark)

I run into this error message 'TypeError: this.props.nextStage is not a function'

As far as I can tell I've followed the tutorial line by line minus some name changes but I still run into this error.

I've probably made an obvious error somehow but I'm stuck and I'd appreciate any guidance as to what the issue might be.

Doing some research it appears it might be a 'binding' issue which I've attempted to implement but in all honesty I'm unsure if I'm even doing that correctly.

The problem seems to also repeat with any functions passed as props

I expect that when I click on the continue button this will trigger a stateSet change that will render the next stage of the log in form.

Instead i end up with this message: TypeError: this.props.nextStage is not a function.

Hopefully I've copied in the relevant code that will aid debug but if it helps by project is here.

https://github.com/BOUNCE8/Log-in-Form/tree/master/src/components

I expect I've broken a load of rules in terms of asking a question so I apologise in advance, I hope someone can shed some light on my issue.

```
export class BasicInfoForm extends Component {
  continue = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.nextStage();
  };

  render() {
    const { values, handleChange } = this.props;
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <React.Fragment>
          <AppBar title="Enter User Details" />
          <TextField
            hintText="Enter your first name"
            floatingLabelText="First Name"
            // onChange={handleChange('firstName')}
            // defaultValue={values.firstName}
          />
          <br />
          <TextField
            hintText="Enter your last name"
            floatingLabelText="Last Name"
            // onChange={handleChange('lastName')}
            // defaultValue={values.lastName}
          />
          <br />
          <TextField
            hintText="Enter your email"
            floatingLabelText="Email"
            // onChange={handleChange('email')}
            // defaultValue={values.email}
          />
          <br />
          <RaisedButton
            label="Continue"
            primary={true}
            style={styles.button}
            onClick={this.continue}
          />
        </React.Fragment>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default BasicInfoForm;


export class MainUserForm extends Component {
  state = {
    stage: 1,
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    email: '',
    city: '',
    country: '',
  };

  // Proceed to next stage on form
  nextStage = () => {
    const { stage } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      stage: stage + 1,
    });
  };

  // Revert to previous stage on form
  prevStage = () => {
    const { stage } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      stage: stage - 1,
    });
  };

  // Handle change in form fields
  handleChange = input => e => {
    this.setState({ [input]: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    const { stage } = this.state;
    const { firstName, lastName, email, city, country } = this.state;
    const values = { firstName, lastName, email, city, country };

    switch (stage) {
      case 1:
        return (
          <BasicInfoForm
            nextStage={this.nextStage}
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
            values={values}
          />
        );
      case 2:
        return <h1>Personal Info Form</h1>;
      case 3:
        return <h1>Confirm Page</h1>;
      case 4:
        return <h1> Complete Page</h1>;

      // no default
    }
  }
}

export default MainUserForm;
```

Comment: Search your code for all occurrences of `BasicInfoForm`. It seems like besides the one within `render` method of `MainUserForm` you have another one (possibly in your `App` component) where `BasicInfoForm` is rendered without properly provided props. Possibly you are simply rendering `BasicInfoForm` somewhere instead of `MainUserForm`....

Comment: Sorry for the late reply,  I do have an instance of basicInfoForm rendered in App but I thought by passing the props in the basicInfoForm and exporting/importing basicInfoForm to the App component that I'd have use of those props?. I'm not even sure if that makes any sense to be honest. I really need to get a grip on this concept but I'm struggling.

Comment: I believe that I could help more if I would take a look at your App.js file. It would be nice if you could edit your question and include the App.js content there or upload the file somewhere and give me a download link...

Comment: I've figured out the issue now, I was rendering basicInfoForm in App instead of MainInfoForm. Thanks Tyschenko, you really helped point me in the right direction.

Comment: That was exactly the point I was trying to lead you to. Glad that you sorted things out. Good luck wit React :)

Comment: Thanks man, I suspect I'll have more questions down the road =P